# How do I customize an ADFS website?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I need to customize some content on an existing ADFS sign in site. By navigating to https://fqdn/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx, I can view the site as it is. But changes that I make with varying commands and script edits do not seem to propagate to the site. As an example:

1. Used `Set-ADFSGlobalWebContent -CompanyName 'example'`

I do not observe a change on the website after this. If I run `Get-ADFSGlobalWebContent` I do see that the CompanyName has been changed, but the actual ADFS website doesn't show anything.

2. Set a line in `Scripts\onload.js` to say "Sign in with your FQDN account". After saving this file, and confirming it is referenced by the currently active ADFS Theme, I check the site to see that the old text (in this case, "Passwod Change", no that's not a typo) is still there.

What am I missing here? I'm very new to ADFS modification, but it's something that needs changing. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I was doing a mix of Windows Server 2016 and 2012 commands and styles. I also discovered that in certain commands, I was targeting an inactive ADFS theme, not the active one. Additionally, the onload.js file needed to be modified in a text editor, and then activated using the following command:

`Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName custom -AdditionalFileResource @{Uri=’/adfs/portal/script/onload.js’;path="D:\inetpub\adfsassets\script\onload.js"}`

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn280950(v%3Dws.11))